# Replace content in div with other content using a slide up transition with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs like the following:

```
<div id="content">
    Content 1
</div>
<div id="rollover-content" style="display: none;">
    Content 2
</div>
```

How can I make it so when the #content div is hovered over by the mouse the #rollover-content div does a 'slide up' transition effect and takes over. Then when the mouse is off of the div #content will slide back.

If you go to [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tilelist/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) and hover over the first tile you will see the effect I am looking for, but I am trying to do it with straight jQuery.

I created the following css class which is a nice container to create a card:

```
.card {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0.5rem 0 1rem 0;
        background-color: #F1F1F1;
        transition: box-shadow .25s;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
        padding: 20px;
}
```

How can I do these transitions in a div with this class wrapped around it?

Comment: `$('#content').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() { $('#rollover-content').slideToggle() })`

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you just need to wrap your content in a couple of divs. Firstly an outer div which is the same size as the content slides within it and has `overflow: hidden` to mask off content outside its bounds. Then another div inside that which holds all the slides to be moved up/down as you hover in and out. Then finally inside that you have your actual content. Here's an example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="content" id="first">
            Content 1
        </div>
        <div class="content" id="second">
            Content 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.slide {
    position: absolute;
}
.content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```js
$('.container').hover(function(e) {
    var $container = $(this), 
        top = e.type == 'mouseenter' ? -$container.height() : 0;
    $container.find('.slide').stop(true).animate({
        top: top
    })
})
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/pcurreur/)

Alternatively you can do it in CSS alone, so long as the `.content` elements will *always* be the height defined in your CSS:

```
.slide:hover {
    top: -150px;
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/pcurreur/1/)

Comment: Why do you use JavaScript?

Comment: Thank you for these excellent examples. Is it me or is the jQuery transition a lot smoother nicer than css.

Comment: It will vary from machine to machine and browser to browser. Generally CSS transitions will be smoother as they are hardware accelerated, whereas JS animation is not.

Comment: I am going to mark this as answer, but is there anyway you can look at the css class at the bottom of my post called card? I would like my squares to look like that and I am having more trouble than I thought applying it to what you gave me.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you view my jsFiddle? It is supposed to be 3 cards side by side. If you hover over the image it should display the description, if you mouseout it should display the picture again. I just can't seem to apply your css only example to it.

Comment: Have you got a link to your fiddle? I can't see it anywhere

Comment: Sorry thought I posted it: https://jsfiddle.net/ja4kw5zp/     So basically I want to use bootstrap and create 3 columns so these cards stack on mobile. If you hover over the image, the entire image gets replaced with the description, if you mouseout the image comes back. The transition should happen to the entire width of the card.

Comment: That's going to be very tricky to achieve (either with jQuery or CSS) as you're using a lot of styles on the `card` which won't work on an absolutely positioned element, such as `margin` to centrally align, along with the padding etc.

Comment: Well then that explains why I'm struggling with it I guess. I wonder if I can just toggle and completely swap the divs. I guess it is the transition part that I would lose then.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any jQuery for this. A couple of lines of CSS can already achieve this effect. A transition is set on `.box-2` to do the effect.

```css
.box-container {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box-1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.box-2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: darkblue;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: height .4s ease-in-out;
}
.box-container:hover .box-2 {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">

  <div class="box-1">

    Hello

  </div>

  <div class="box-2">

    New content

  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Note that this isn't the exact same behaviour as the OP showed in the demo page, although as a CSS only solution it's very nice.

Comment: Can you show me how I could incorporate it with cards that look like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ja4kw5zp/